# How do I convert Google's DateTime object to a long-type value?

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I am trying to integrate a database with a web application that extracts event data from Google Calendar API which inputs the data into the database. The following code is identical to the Quickstart class provided by Google.

I basically want 'DateTime start' to be converted to 'long start'. I need the long value for SQL.

```
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;

// ...

DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Events events = service.events().list(calendarId)
                .setTimeMin(now)
                .setOrderBy("startTime")
                .setSingleEvents(true)
                .execute();
    List<Event> items = events.getItems();
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No upcoming events found.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Upcoming events");
        for (Event event : items) {
            DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
            DateTime end = event.getEnd().getDateTime();
            if (start == null) {
                start = event.getStart().getDate();
            }
            System.out.printf("%s\n", start.toString());
```

Comment: Call `DateTime.getValue()`? [The method isn't helpfully documented](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/DateTime), but it's what I'd try first.

Comment: @AndyTurner If I use `getValue()`, it converts `2019-05-24T03:00:00.000-07:00` to `1558692000000`. I would like for the SQL to interpret it as `2019-05-24 03:00:00+00`

Comment: `201905240300000000700` looks like a string representation with no interpuctation. That's not the usual `long` value you get from a timestamp.

Comment: Don't store it like that. Store it in a well-known standard format, such as an RFC3339-formatted string.

Comment: I edited my comment. I misinterpreted it earlier...

Answer (score 0):

Google has implemented the Rfc3339 parser in Google HTTP Client Library. You can try parsing it first and the use the DateTime.getValue() function to convert it into long.
You may also try using the DatetimeFormatter to format it to the way you want the value.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
            .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
public void convertDatetime() {
    String timeStamp = "2019-05-24T11:32:26.553955473Z";

    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parseRfc3339(timeStamp);
    long millis = dateTime.getValue();

    String result = formatter.format(new Date(millis).toInstant());
```